# Removing epsilon-transitions from context-free grammar

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I have a context-free grammar; I have to remove epsilon-transitions:

$S \to 0A0|0$

$A \to BC|2| CCC$

$B \to 1C | 3D | \epsilon$

$C \to AA3 | \epsilon$

$D \to AAB | 2$

---

By alghoritm , I create $N_{0}$ that will hold all nonterminals that contain $\epsilon$ and in the next steps I add nonterminals that have rule that contains only nonterminals from previous iteration of $N$ e.g.,

1) $N_{0} = \{\}$

2) $N_{1} = \{B,C\}$

3) $N_{2} = \{B,C,A\}$

4) $N_{3} = \{B,C,A,D,S\}$

Now I have to adjust rules.  We can remove nonterminals in $N_{3}$ object from rules, thus we have to create all combinations without it, e.g.,

$S \to 0A0|00|0$

$A \to BC | B | C | CCC | CC$

$B \to 1C | 1 | 3D | 3$

$C \to AA3| A3 | 3$

$D \to AAB | AA | A | AB | B | 2$

We see that no nonterminal is useless, so is this the final context-free grammar? Or did I make mistakes somewhere?

Thanks for answers and help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first phase of the conversion I'm familiar with (e.g., Hopcroft and Ullman, *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation*), you collect what are known as *nullable variables*.  These are the nonterminals that can produce the empty string.  In the grammar you gave, $S$ is not one of those; $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are.

In the second phase---as you say---you "adjust the rules."  For each production that contains nullable variables in the right-hand side, and for each nonempry subset of those variables, add a production obtained by removing that subset from the right-hand side, unless removing the subset leaves the empty string.  Apart from omitting $A \to 2$, your resulting grammar looks OK.